# BigInteger modulus not positive exception

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a function which decides whether a given BigInteger is a prime number or not. In the main class I made a call to that function with an argument passed. Now when I try to compile, I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\me\Downloads>java RSA_n_prime2_using_int
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger: modulus not positive
        at java.math.BigInteger.mod(Unknown Source)
        at RSA_n_prime2_using_int.prime_check(RSA_n_prime2_using_int.java:92)
        at RSA_n_prime2_using_int.main(RSA_n_prime2_using_int.java:20)
```

My code looks something like this

```
public static boolean prime_check(BigInteger val)
{
    BigInteger prime_chk=new BigInteger("0");
    //System.out.println("in the function");
    boolean isprime=true;
    BigInteger prime_value=val.add(BigInteger.ZERO);

    if(val.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)||val.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) 
        return false;
    for(prime_chk.valueOf(2);prime_chk.compareTo(prime_value)<0;prime_chk.add(BigInteger.ONE))
    {
        if((prime_value.mod(prime_chk)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            {
                isprime=false;
                break;
            }
    }
    return isprime;
}
```

In the main function, the call is made as follows

```
s1 = new BigInteger("1021");//s1=(int)Math.round(Math.random()*1000)%30;
if(prime_check(p1))
{
        System.out.println(p1+" is prime");
}
```

Please help me in finding, where I have went wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `BigInteger.isProbablePrime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having set `prime_chk` to zero at the start of the function, you then do:

```
for (prime_chk.valueOf(2); blah; blah ) {
    if((prime_value.mod(prime_chk)) {
        blah;
    }
}
```

That first part of the `if` statement (`prime_chk.valueOf(2)`) doesn't actually *change* `prime_chk`, it simply evaluates the `2` and creates a big integer of that value (which you appear to then throw away). Thus, when you execute `prime_value.mod(prime_chk)`, `prime_chk` is *still* set to zero, hence your exception (some may argue the case but zero is neither negative *nor* positive - in any case, `x mod 0` is a problematic operation regardless of the arguments raised).

Perhaps you might want to change the initial part of the `if` to something like:

```
for (prime_chk = BigInteger.valueOf(2); blah; blah ) {
```

This will actually *change* `prime_chk` to be `2` and hence avoid your exception.

---

One other point, you may be able to save a lot of cycles if you limit `prime_chk` to between `2` and the *square root* of the test number. If you haven't found a divisor below that, it's mathematically guaranteed you won't find one above. The normal method would be along the lines of (pseudo-code, obviously):

```
def isPrime (val):
    for (chk = 2; chk * chk <= val; chk++):
        if (val % chk) == 0:
            return false
    return true
```